# how to decode utf-8 cyrrilic text fron http response?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to decode  this text using dart packages? i am using http package. Bacause the encoded string is cyrrilic and my http response is:

```
   {"items":[{"id":1,"title":"\u0421\u0430\u043c\u043e\u043a\u0430\u0442\u044b","slug":"samokaty"},{"id":2,"title":"\u0412\u0435\u043b\u043e\u0441\u0438\u043f\u0435\u0434\u044b","slug":"velosipedy"}
```

I am doing this:

```
  Future<ProductCategories?> fetchCategories() async {
    var response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse(_baseUrl + '/api/productCategories'));
    var jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    print(response.body);
    try{
      return ProductCategories.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    }catch(e, s){
      log('error occurs', error: e, stackTrace: s);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to interpret `\u0421\u0430\u043c\u043e\u043a\u0430\u0442\u044b` as a string?

Comment: Your json is not valid please provide the full response

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered on my question. It really works.  I totally forgot that this kind of responses should be encoded slightly different that i used to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes))
```

to convert the encoding to utf8

Answer (score 0):

Try encode your response.body and decode again its printing below output :

```
var res = json.encode(response.body);
 print(json.decode(res));
```

output : hope this helps

```
{items: [{id: 1, title: Самокаты, slug: samokaty}, {id: 2, title: Велосипеды, slug: velosipedy}]}
```